# Is it necessary to always use async in all functions when await is used in Swift

Tags: swift, async-await

I have the following example in Swift:

```
func call1() { call2() }
func call2() { call3() }
func call3() { call4() }
func call4() { call5() }
func call5() { print("finish") }
```

If I want to make the call5() an async function, is it mandatory to change all other calls to async to make call5() to work properly?

Comment: No, it is not mandatory for async functions to call only other async functions.

Comment: But Xcode is complaining about that in my code, it shows me the error ('async' call in a function that does not support concurrency ). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling an `async` function requires a matching `await`. To make it work in a sync context you need to wrap the call in a task.

```
Task { await call5() }
```

This will spawn a concurrent task on the current thread.

Here is the WWDC talk with more details about structured concurrency. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10134/

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to make them all `async`, but you might consider doing so. Specifically, by making them all asynchronous, you enjoy two benefits:

- The caller of `call1` can now know when the whole sequence is done, all the way down to `call5`.
- If the caller of `call1` gets canceled, structured concurrency will make sure that the cancelation is automatically propagated all the way down to `call5`.

So, you have two options:

1. Leave `call1`-`call4` synchronous, but have `call4` invoke `call5` with `Task { … }`. As described above, the caller of `call1` loses the ability to know when `call5` is done and you cannot enjoy automatic cancelation propagation:

   ```swift
   func call1() { call2() }
   func call2() { call3() }
   func call3() { call4() }
   func call4() { Task { await call5() } }    // opts out of structured concurrency
   func call5() async { … }
   ```
2. You can make them all asynchronous, so that the caller of `call1` can know when the whole sequence is done and enjoy automatic cancelation propagation.

   ```swift
   func call1() async { await call2() }
   func call2() async { await call3() }
   func call3() async { await call4() }
   func call4() async { await call5() }
   func call5() async { … }
   ```

In short, neither approach is necessarily right or wrong: It depends upon precisely what `call5` is doing asynchronously.

Also, if refactoring a legacy code base, you don’t have to jump to option 2 immediately, but rather you can start with option 1, and slowly progress to option 2 over time. See WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) for examples of how you might do this migration over time.

Comment: Hi, the option 2 is exactly what I want to avoid. Option 1 is fine. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, I figured as much. I just wanted to outline the implications of that approach (esp for future readers). Happy coding!